# Differences between `su` and `su-to-root`?

Tags: su

There are other questions on this forums about the usage of `su`, `su -`, `su root`... etc.

But I have found none about the `su-to-root` command, and I would like to understand the basics of its usage.

I hope this example could be useful: on *Kali Linux v2.0* live (desktop PC version) the installer uses this `.desktop` direct link :

```
root@kali:~$ more /usr/share/applications/debian-installer-launcher.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Install Kali
Comment=Install this system permanently to your hard disk
Exec=su-to-root -X -c /usr/sbin/debian-installer-launcher
Icon=debian-installer-launcher
Type=Application
Categories=Application;System;
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
```

If I would like to manually start the installer from a X Windows terminal, must I use

```
su-to-root -X -c /usr/sbin/debian-installer-launcher
```

or can I simply do:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/debian-installer-launcher
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

su-to-root is simply a GUI front end for su. If you're comfortable in the terminal, then using sudo should work fine.

For more information: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/su-to-root.1.html